# Why can I divide Single by Variant in Delphi, and what is it for?

Tags: delphi, floating-point, variant

I was surprised to see, that floating-point values could be divided by a Variant in Delphi. A simple example of what can be done:

```
var
  v: Variant;
begin
  v := 2.3;
  Tag := 5.1 div v; // 2
  Tag := 5.1 mod v; // 1
  Tag := 5.1 div 2; // [dcc32 Error] E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
  Tag := 5.1 mod 2; // [dcc32 Error] E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
end;
```

It looks like Delphi rounds the left-part and right-part before doing the `div`/`mod` operation.

I would expect above code to produce errors at compile-time in all 4 lines, since my understanding is that div/mod are not applicable to floating-point values no matter what. Clearly this is not the case.

Why can I divide Single by Variant in Delphi, and what is it needed for?

Comment: That's just variant type coercion. Variants are designed to allow as many type conversions as imaginable. If you want to learn more about why then you should look at the MS COM docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Variants in Expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types_(Delphi)#Variants_in_Expressions):

> If an expression combines variants with statically-typed values, the statically-typed values are automatically converted to variants.

This means that the float typed literal is converted to a variant first.

Then both variants are implicitly converted to integer values to match the operator before doing the div/mod operation.
[Variant Type Conversions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types_(Delphi)#Variant_Type_Conversions)

> ..and what is it needed for?

Just to be as versatile as possible and fully support OLE.

Comment: You don't think that this type was designed to match the COM variant type?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, ok that was too obvious. Updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: To be picky, I don't think "OLE" is the correct term here. should be "COM".

Comment: @Kobik, OLE Automation uses OleVariants to pass data. COM can also pass OleVariant data. You can say that COM is the implementation part of OLE, and many times the terms are used interchangeably. Marco Cantu says in one of his books that the Delphi variants library is built to support OLE. ["To provide full OLE support, the 32-bit version of Delphi includes the Variant data type."](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/English/ch10var.htm)